# Can a single app link against both MySQL/Percona and Sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have an application that has both RDBMS and fulltext search needs. I am using Percona for the RDBMS and want to use Sphinx for the fulltext search. I know that they both use the same or very similar protocol. My question is: can I link against both the MySQL/Percona client library and the Sphinx client library? Or should I use the Percona client library only and use it to connect to the Sphinx searchd? Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mysql client to connect to database, and then a sphinxapi client to connect to sphinx. (using the SphinxAPI protcol)

Or can instead use the mysql client, to connect (seperately) to the mysql instance. And again to connect to the sphinx instance- using sphinxQL protocol.

The second is recommended. As only need a mysql client for both. And SphinxQL is actully more featureful than the API, and not so prone to compatibility issues between versions.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt an informative answer. I was hoping to just use the one library and it is very useful to know that SphinxQL is more feature-rich than the API. That makes the choice obvious.